# Apply a CSS rule to the parent selector and a more specific selector without repeating the line

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

I am working on a project in Ionic and this is the first time I am using SCSS. I've understood much of the concepts though I've a little confusion, the code below will help you understand it.

The component is the `ion-item` component and for some reason the `border-radius` doesn't work directly in an iOS playform unless we use `!important`, works fine on Android and Windows platforms, to remedy that I currently have

```
page-subscription-list {
    & ion-item {
        background-color: color($colors, light, base);
        border-radius: 10px;
        &.item-ios {
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not want to use `!important` because it is known to make the workflow difficult, I know using it here wouldn't matter much but I intend to keep it away entirely.

As you can see `border-radius: 10px;` is currently being there twice, once for `page-subscription-list ion-item` and then for `page-subscription-list ion-item.item-ios`

My question is that is there any kind of functions within SASS that lets us use the same line of CSS rule for both the specific selector `ion-item.item-ios` and then the parent selector itself i.e `ion-item`

I am reading this : https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/, but it doesn't seem to help me with my problem, probably I am looking at the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: `ion-item` is already going to be selected and `border-radius` will be applied on it, why do you need to explicitly apply it again on `ion-item.item-ios`?

Comment: Because when the app is loaded in an iOS platform the border-radius is overridden by a CSS class that's a part of the Ionic framework specific for the iOS platform, as for Android and Windows the border-radius works by simply using `ion-item`, to override the styles for iOS platform I either need to use `!important` or a more specific selector like `ion-item.item-ios`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that even though there is any function that lets us do this it will always end up having two selectors separated by by coma, there is no automagical way to reduce the lines of code that is going to be generated.

So I decided to go with this.

```
& ion-item,
& ion-item.item-ios {
    background-color: color($colors, light, base);
    border-radius: 10px;
```

And from an Ionic framework point of view I can do this:

```
& ion-item {
    &.item {
        background-color: color($colors, light, base);
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
}
```

Since `ion-item` also has the `item` class in it along with the platform specific classes like `item-md` and `item-ios`.

If you have suggestions please do comment or answer this question! :)